# Do we need to add Publishing Service Content Availability Solr Fields to the Managed Schema?

Tags: solr, publishing-service

We have configured publishing service in our environment and we came across with below post. Should we manually add the fields in SOLR managed schema?

isAvailable
versionsunrisedate
versionsunsetdate
publishablefrom
publishableto

https://blog.senktas.net/2019/08/10/deep-dive-to-content-availability-feature-in-publishing-service/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you do not need to add these fields to the Solr Managed Schema.  This is because these fields in the content database are listed as strings.

There is a dynamic field setting in the Managed Schema that will classify these fields as "strings".

As such, and as listed in the blog post, these fields will automatically appear in the document for the returned items as such:

[image: Snippet of Image from blog post in question]

You will still want to make sure that the proper configuration on the CD's are created for your specific Sitecore site.  Notice in the blog post that the *Sitecore.Publishing.Service.ContentAvailability.config* out of the box only contains a configuration for the "website" site, which is Sitecore's default site.

You'll want to make sure you include other sites, as appropriate here.

Edit:  The _IsAvailable field is setup as a virtual field in the search query and computed at Runtime.  There's a great answer [here](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/a/5707/246) that explains the difference between Computed Fields and Virtual Fields.  You don't need to add it to the schema because the value is not stored in the index itself.

Virtual Fields have draw backs as they can cause queries to be expensive and slow depending on what you are doing.

Comment: Should we add _isavailable field in schema file?

Comment: @Astle I've updated my answer to answer your question.